# How many times can I get a reward card?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

Do legendary duelists drop their reward cards only once or can I get them several times? For example the flute of summoning dragon?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit, you can get as many cards as possible, only depends on your luck.